# When I click on a reply in the discussion community I get redirected to a "page cannot be displayed" screen, what did I do?

Tags: community

I am  creating a discussion community. I added a test question to see how it would display. When I select the hyperlink for the question I get "web page cannot be displayed" What did I do wrong?

Comment: Add more details like SharePoint version etc.

Comment: I am using Share Point 2013. The discussion board/community was set up with no problems. The categories are set. When a question is posted under a category it populates in the discussion list. When you click on the post, rather than lead you to the page with the post and options to reply, it directs me to "web page cannot be displayed". I will note it was working just fine prior to my deleting a test post.

Comment: Is it directing you to flat.aspx file?

Comment: I've faced alike issue when one of the site admins has deleted the _Flat.aspx_ page - the one responsible for discussion display. Check if the same has happened.

Comment: Can it be restored?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was extremely simple. I just had to restore my edits from the recycle bin and it is working just fine now.